# ¿Se puede hacer una aplicación con Java swing en el editor online Jdoodle?

Tags: java, java-swing

Estuve trabajando en el editor [jdoodle](https://www.jdoodle.com) para poder apoyar a los alumnos que tengo los cuales tienen problemas para instalar en sus equipos un editor como *Netbeans* u otro, me pareció interesante el que puedan ejecutar sus programas en este editor online, veo que con Scanner no hay problema para la solicitud de datos al usuario.

Pero he intentado con Swing y me da el siguiente error:

> ```
> Exception in thread "main" java.awt.HeadlessException:  No X11 DISPLAY
> variable was set, but this program performed an operation which
> requires it.  at
> java.desktop/java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.checkHeadless(GraphicsEnvironment.java:208)
>   at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.<init>(Window.java:548)     at
> java.desktop/java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:423)    at
> java.desktop/java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:388)    at
> java.desktop/javax.swing.SwingUtilities$SharedOwnerFrame.<init>(SwingUtilities.java:1919)
>   at
> java.desktop/javax.swing.SwingUtilities.getSharedOwnerFrame(SwingUtilities.java:1995)
>   at
> java.desktop/javax.swing.JOptionPane.getRootFrame(JOptionPane.java:1689)
>   at
> java.desktop/javax.swing.JOptionPane.showInputDialog(JOptionPane.java:580)
>   at
> java.desktop/javax.swing.JOptionPane.showInputDialog(JOptionPane.java:527)
>   at
> java.desktop/javax.swing.JOptionPane.showInputDialog(JOptionPane.java:475)
>   at
> java.desktop/javax.swing.JOptionPane.showInputDialog(JOptionPane.java:439)
>   at Ejemplo1.main(Ejemplo1.java:9)
> ```

Y este es el código, pero esta en tecleado en el editor online *jdoodle*.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane; //importamos la clase JOptionPane que sirve para mostrar cuadros de dialogo 
public class Ejemplo1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        //Alumno: ADOLFO ANGEL HAU CANO 
       //Materia: PROGRAMACION BASICA    Grupo: INFO-307
      // CONALEP, VALLADOLID, YUCATAN 
      int horastrabajadas; // Declaramos el tipo de variable a utilizar.
      float salariototal; // Declaramos la segunda variable a utilizar.
      horastrabajadas = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite el total de horas trabajadas"));
      if (horastrabajadas <= 40) { //Declaramos la condicion para el salario del obrero
          salariototal = horastrabajadas * 16; //Si trabaja menos de 40 horas muestra en la pantalla el salario sin el pago extra.
      }
        else { //Si no cumple la primera condicion  del salario del obrero.
          salariototal = (40*16) + (horastrabajadas-40)*20; //SI trabaja mas de 40 horas muestra en la pantalla el salario total incluido el pago extra.         
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"El salario total es"+salariototal);
  
      }
   }
    
}
```

Gracias de antemano por su ayuda, saludos.

Comment: Con bajarte la JDK y tener un editor de texto te vale.

Comment: Con https://replit.com/ si se puede, tal vez te sirva como alternativa a jdoodle. Tiene la contra de que la página consume más recursos.

Answer (score 0):

Es simple. El ambiente que indicas que estás usando, te está diciendo que no tiene un entorno gráfico para pintar la GUI en Swing

```
Exception in thread "main" java.awt.HeadlessException:  No X11 DISPLAY
variable was set, but this program performed an operation which
requires it.
```

La recomendación es que asistas a quienes tienen líos con los IDE y comiencen por instalar el JDK y desde ahí, usar incluso bloc de notas y compilar los .java por línea de comandos si es necesario, pero necesitas un ambiente con manejador de ventanas (con interfaz gráfica, mejor dicho) para usar Swing.

En tu problema actual, como no tienes cómo conectarte por SSH al servidor de jdoodle, pues esa opción no la vas a tener. ¿No te suena hacer/usar un manual detallado, paso a paso de cómo instalar el IDE o la herramienta que necesiten? Seguro hay muchos disponibles en línea y es mucho más fácil.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu apoyo, saludos.